# Minimum distance from a point to the hyperplane (using Kuhn-Tucker conditions)

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Find the minimum Euclidean distance between a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and the hyperplane $$\left\{x:w^{T}x=b\right\}$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $b \in \mathbb R$.

I must formulate the problem as an optimization problem with constraints and deduce the Kuhn-Tucker conditions for this formulation.

Comment: Rather than remove the convex-optimization tag (which seems perfectly suited to this problem), a clearer statement of what you want to ask (not what you "must" do) would improve the Question.  After all the objective function and the constraint seem rather evident in the present problem statement (minimize distance between $x$ and $x_0$ where $x$ is constrained to the hyperplane).  State the obvious and it will be easier to spot where your difficulties lie.

Answer (score 4):

According to your notation, you can tackle the problem trying to minimize the objective function $f(x) :=(x-x_0)^T (x-x_0)$, i.e., the square of the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $x_0$, subject to the equality constraint $g(x) := w^Tx - b = 0$, i.e., $x$ belongs to the hyperplane.

The Kuhn-Tucker formulation of this problem is specified by the following equations:
$$(i)\;\; \nabla f(x) = \lambda\nabla g(x);$$
$$(ii)\;\; g(x) = 0;$$
where $\nabla h(x) = (\partial h(x)/\partial x_1,\ldots,\partial h(x)/\partial x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ denoted the gradient of any function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar.

Whenever $x^*$ is a local optimum, it must fulfill these equations. While equation $(ii)$ is just the equality constraint, the rationale behind the equation $(i)$ can be understood as follows:

If $x^*$ fulfills equation $(i)$ then $\nabla f(x^*)$ and $\nabla g(x^*)$ are collinear, meaning that $\nabla f(x^*)$ is perpendicular to the hypersurface $G$ of points fulfilling the constraint $g(x)=0$ locally at $x^*$, hence the direction where $f$ reaches its highest rate of change locally at $x^*$ (i.e., its gradient at $x^*$) is perpendicular to $G$ at $x^*$. In the case of a local optimum $x^*$ this is the case given sufficient regularity conditions, e.g., $f$ and $g$ continuously differentiable at $x^*$.

It can be readily seen that $\nabla f(x) = 2(x-x_0)$ and $\nabla g(x) = w$. Consequently, the Kuhn-Tucker equations of the problem can be written as:
$$(i)\;\; 2(x-x_0) = \lambda w;$$
$$(ii)\;\; w^T x = b.$$

Solving for $x$ in equation $(i)$ yields $x=\frac{\lambda}{2} w + x_0$. Plugging the expression of $x$ in equation $(ii)$ leads to 
$$\frac{\lambda}{2}w^Tw + w^Tx_0 = b,$$
which is then solved for $\lambda$, 
$$\lambda = \frac{2}{w^Tw}(w^Tx_0 - b).$$
Finally, plugging the value for $\lambda$ in the expression of $x$ will lead to the unique local optimum $x^*$,
$$x^*= \frac{w^Tx_0-b}{w^Tw}w+x_0.$$

Finally, the minimum distance is given by the distance between the local optimum $x^*$ and $x_0$, i.e.,
$$d(x^*,x_0) = \sqrt{(x^*-x_0)^T (x^*-x_0)} = \left|\frac{w^Tx_0-b}{w^Tw}\right|\sqrt{w^Tw}.$$